# Automating FTP Folder Synchronization for Uploading via Command Line

Tags: windows, ftp, sync

I'm developing a website and I have FTP access for uploading local files to a directory on the site via FTP. I'd like to automate this deployment process as much as possible using the command line.

Is there a **Windows** command line utility that I can use to help me further automate my process of synchronizing a local directory with a remote directory via FTP with this task?

Comment: You can write a PowerShell [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell) to do this.  The standard FTP client, out of the box on Windows, has always been IE.  If you want additional functionality then that provides you would have to go with a third-party option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upload files using the command line on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/253245/how-do-i-upload-files-using-the-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

### Automate FTP Folder Synchronization with WinSCP

I've successfully completed such tasks using the awesome and ever so cool [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) product. I've provided you a sample **Batch Script** as well to help setup such a task for automation and thus providing you a rather full and complete answer to help satisfy your needs.

> **Essentially you will:**
>
> 1. Define the FTP connection within the [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) GUI
> 2. Save the defined FTP connection and give it a name that indicates what it pertains
> 3. Use the FTP connection name in the script to open the connection for the FTP commands—see the **Batch Script** section
>
>    [image]
>      [image]
>      [image]

---

### Batch Script

In the below batch script you will want to be sure these variables are set with the correct values: `localdir`, `remotedir`, `winscplogin`, and `logfile` so be sure those are set to point to the correct folders, WinSCP defined FTP connection, and log file—the rest should just work as-is.

```
@ECHO ON

:SetFileLogVariables
SET localdir=C:\dev\site123
SET remotedir="dev\site123"
SET logfile=C:\logs\FTP_dev_site123_sync.log

:SetPrgVariables
SET prgwinscp="C:\Program Files\WinSCP3\WinSCP.com"
SET winscplogin="DevSiteSync"
SET winscpfile=%temp%\~tmpWinSCPFTPSyncT_%~N0.txt
IF EXIST "%winscpfile%" DEL /Q /F "%winscpfile%"

:SetWinSCPSyncCommand
SET ftpcmd=synchronize remote "%localdir%\"

:ftpout
ECHO.                                                                   >> %logfile%
ECHO ***************************  FTP OUT  ***************************  >> %logfile%
ECHO Synchronizing files to %winscplogin% server  on %date% at %time%   >> %logfile%

ECHO option batch on          >> %winscpfile%
ECHO option confirm off       >> %winscpfile%
ECHO option transfer binary   >> %winscpfile%
ECHO open %winscplogin%       >> %winscpfile%
ECHO cd %remotedir%           >> %winscpfile%
ECHO %ftpcmd%                 >> %winscpfile%
ECHO close                    >> %winscpfile%
ECHO exit                     >> %winscpfile%

ECHO %winscpfile%                                >> %logfile%
TYPE %winscpfile%                                >> %logfile%
ECHO ------------------------------------------- >> %logfile%
%prgwinscp% /script=%winscpfile%                 >> %logfile%
ECHO ------------------------------------------- >> %logfile%
IF EXIST "%winscpfile%" DEL /Q /F "%winscpfile%"
ECHO Transmission complete on %date% at %time%   >> %logfile%
EXIT
```

---

> ### WinSCP Connection Configuration Note
>
> You will probably want to tell the WinSCP defined FTP connection to
>   NOT **Remember the last directory used** since the script will go to
>   the folder explicitly.
>
> You complete this by highlighting the defined FTP connection name
>   within the WinSCP GUI and then select **Edit** | **Advanced** |
>   **Directories** | uncheck the box next to **Remember the last directory used** | **OK** | **Save**.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

---

> ### [synchronize](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize)
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> synchronize local|remote|both [ <local directory> [ <remote directory> ] ]
> ```
>
> **Remarks**
>
> When the first parameter is `local`, changes from remote directory are
>   applied to local directory. When the first parameter is `remote`,
>   changes from the local directory are applied to the remote directory.
>   When the first parameter is `both`, both local and remote directories
>   can be modified.
>
> When directories are not specified, current working directories are
>   synchronized.
>
> **Note:** Overwrite confirmations are always off for the command.
>
> Switches:
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[source](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [Scripting and Task Automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)
- [Directory Synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full)
- [Synchronize Files with FTP Server or SFTP Server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize)

Answer (score 1):

I have used successfully the venerable and free
[NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/).

Example usage :

```
ncftpput -u user -p password ftp.server.com /server-folder file-path
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `bash` `ftp` script can transfer over a file:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
FILE='test.txt'

ftp $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
USER $USER
PASS $PASSWD
passive
ls
cd test
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Easier than writing you own script to loop over files and folders, use `lsftp`:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASS='password'
TARGETFOLDER='/test'
SOURCEFOLDER='/mnt/c/test'

lftp -f "
set ssl:verify-certificate no
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
mirror --reverse --delete --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
```