# how to fill fields of a dialog in ie with powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I have the following box that needs to be filled with a name and a password, how can I handle it with powershell from the InternetExplorer.Application object or with another object using powershell's own libraries:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I also believe that this is not possible: `or with another object using powershell's own libraries`

Comment: in computing everything is possible

Comment: well,  good luck

Comment: @ortiga A few posts for additional starting ideas to expand on potentially: https://superuser.com/questions/1369904/encrypting-the-password-value-used-to-send-an-email-via-a-bat-file/1370096#1370096 and https://superuser.com/questions/1239624/automating-ftp-folder-synchronization-for-uploading-via-command-line/1239776#1239776 and https://superuser.com/questions/1334959/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-obfuscate-the-password-in-a-ftp-script-using-windows-f/1334988#1334988

Answer (score 0):

Typically when accessing a website through basic authentication you can include the username and password inline with the URL like this:

`http://<username>:<password>@192.168.1.1`

Or with HTTPS simply:

`https://<username>:<password>@192.168.1.1`

So, for example if my username is `baa` and my password is `hunter2` then the URL would be `http://baa:hunter2@192.168.1.1`.

Depending on your workflow this may be feasible.

Comment: it gives me a security error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800C000E), thanks for the help but it doesn't work for me , since the application goes through https

Comment: @ortiga you may need to add `http://192.168.1.1` into your Trusted Sites Zone, see [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-a-trusted-site-in-windows-10)

Comment: To go along with that link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/security-privacy/ie-security-zones-registry-entries.

Comment: @ortiga HTTPS should still work too, add the HTTPS site to the Trusted Sites Zone `https://192.168.1.1`

Comment: that would be pretty insecure i can't do that

Comment: @ortiga Explore WinSCP and defining a connection there and then automating the file exchange upload or download operations without exposing the credential. Even if you could AutoIT to look for the title of the prompt, and then fill it in with the username and password, that is still technically insecure per running in memory. Another idea is to pass the password to the script as an argument at runtime so the logic uses a URL such as `http://baa:%~1@192.168.1.1` where with batch `%~1` is the placeholder only for the value that's passed in at runtime. The script does not contain the password.

Comment: @ortiga You could even build some PowerShell around the connection process, call a URL with the password, and pass the password in at runtime as a base64 encoded value, have PowerShell convert the first argument back to cleartext at run time to build and call the URL, but the script nor the passing of the first value would not be in cleartext. Someone could technically decode the base64 value of the passed argument though to get that value. There are a few ways of doing this sort of thing, I think WinSCP handles file exchanges with FTP very well though: https://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: it doesn't work because the url is type www......com/index.html